# Does every net has a convergent subnet in a compact uniform space?

Tags: general-topology, nets, uniform-spaces

We know that

**Result 1:** In a metric space compactness implies sequential compactness, that is, if $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space then every sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ has a convergent subsequence.

In my proof of **Result 1,** I utilized **Cantor Intersection Theorem** which is not available for Nets.

I wonder whether an analogous result hold in an uniform space for nets, that is,

> If $(X,\mathcal U)$ is an compact uniform space and $(S_n)_{n\in D},D$ being a directed set, is a net in it then can we conclude that there exists a convergent subnet of $(S_n)_{n\in D}?$

Please help!

Comment: More generally, this holds for  a compact topological space.

Answer (score 1):

I add this as an additional answer, since I guess the OP meant by *subnet* something different than the meaning of the Wikipedia article cited by Yuval Peres.

Please check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnet_(mathematics)) for the definition of subnet as meant by Wikipedia. For instance, as is mentioned in this article, a subnet of a sequence need not be  a sequence. I guess the OP meant by subnet a net indexed by a cofinal subset of the index set. Is this correct?

Indeed, the Stone-Cech compactification of the integers does not contain any non-trivial sequence. In particular, the sequence $1, 2, ...$ does not contain a convergent sub*sequence*, which gives a **negative** answer to the question, if my guess was correct.

BTW, convergence and compactness are topological concepts. Furthermore, each compact space has a uniform structure, which induces its topology. Hence, the question should be asking for compact *topological* spaces rather than for uniform spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is positive, see compactness in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Characterizations_of_topological_properties